# finding if string is already escaped or not?

Tags: php

I am getting following data

```
<font color=\"#ff0000\" face=\"Verdana\" size=\"5\">hello there</font><br/>
```

I have 2 questions

- How can I find whether quotes and other things are already escaped (i.e., already preceeded by \ or not)?
- I will be storing this string to one of the fields in database table. Should I convert all HTML special characters to entities like `<` should be converted to  `&lt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing the data into a database, you don't need to convert the HTML entities. You just need to escape the characters that have special meaning in MySQL, using `mysql_real_escape_string()` in PHP for instance. An even better method is using a library like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) (this will take care of escaping the variables for you).

For displaying the HTML data (unescaped), you can use a function like `stripslashes` to remove the slashes. On a sidenote: how come you don't know if the string is escaped or not? If it comes from another section of your application, you should know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is best to be safe than sorry and just use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove any slash that could  be present.

Answer (score 0):

a. I think this regex will do the job:

```
[^\\]["]
```

This regex will be true if there is any " that's not escaped. You can add as many characters as you want to the second set (["]) to make sure they're escaped.

Answer (score 0):

- You can strip slashes and add them again
- You need not to encode entities to store them in DataBase.
  You need it only if you will print it in HTML as literraly string (not as tags) (i.e you want to see `<` char)

Comment: Certainly using stripslashes() is the only sensible way to normalize the data but you **MUST** "encode entities to store them in DataBase" - but whenever you send data outside of PHP you must use the method appropriate to the destination of the data - i.e. for a database, use bound parameters or mysql_escape_string() or equeivalent (addslashes is **NOT** the same thing).    This is *why* magic_quotes are deprecated.

Comment: To stop people hacking your data / defacing your site / destroying your data / stealing confidential information.

Comment: I know that it should be esacped but for printing as part of HTML not for storing. To store you need not anything except mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: "except mysql_real_escape_string" - where was that in the previous respone? http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

At some later point you want this HTML to be used to build a webpage, right? Both escaping the quotes and replacing the HTML special characters with entities will only give you additional work then. So my suggestion is to use parametrized query to avoid the "is the quotes escaped" problem and not to replace the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
$a=addslashes(stripslashes($a));
```

then both slashed or unslashed "/' would be slashed.